# Apple's SBSendEmail example code doesn't send attachments anymore with OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, email, attachment, send, osx-elcapitan

I've just installed OSX El Capitan. 
I have an application that sends Email on OSX. It was working great on previous OSX. 
Now, with El capitan you can still send text but you never receive the attachments.
Thank you for any help.
François

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .

If you put the code for the attachment upper in the lines of code then it works.

With OSX el Capitan, the email is passed to the application MAIL before the attachment is set. So if you start by coding the attachment, then it works.

François.